# Android GCM Missing Registration C#

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement a push notification using the Google GCM, but, when I try to send a notification to GCM I'm getting the `MissingRegistration` error.

I'm using fake registration ids so far but I think that something like 'Registration not found' is raised in this case, right?

Here my C# piece of code

```
    public static void send(List<String> clientRegistrationIds, GcmData data)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(SEND_URL);

        // Headers.
        request.Method = POST;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", API_KEY));
        request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new GcmRequest(clientRegistrationIds, data));
        Console.WriteLine(postData);

        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = request.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(sResponseFromServer);

        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
    }
```

The serialized postData variable:

```
{"registration_ids":["123"],"data":{"message":"New request!"}}
```

My response:

```
Error=MissingRegistration
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: Changing the content-type to `application/json` worked. Now i'm getting the error that I was expecting: `InvalidRegistration`. BUT, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` wasn't supposed to be the correct Content-Type?

Comment: Register a real device and get a genuine I'd. In any case "123" is much too short, real regids are much longer.

Comment: Hi. I've edited my question. I've changed the `content-type` to `application/json` and worked. But, i'm confused because I've read that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` was the correct approach. But thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the ContentType to `application/json` and it worked.